# How can I lookup data about a food from its barcode number?

Tags: ios, cordova, barcode-scanner

I am currently designing an iOS application for helping diabetics to manage their condition.

One feature I am working on is a barcode scanner, where the user will be able to take a picture of a barcode (as they are shopping) and get back information on the product based on its barcode.

With this information, I will create a nutrition score of 1-10 for the diabetic.

My question is, is there a way I can use the scanned barcode to get information on the particular food product?? I realize that the barcode is just a number, and that in supermarkets barcodes information are stored in a supermarket database. Is there anyway I would have access to an online db of food products?

Comment: What you want? Scanning of barcode or access to online db of food products?

Comment: I need to access an online db of food products. I know how to scan the barcode. I want to query the online db of food products with the scanned barcode, and get the nutritional information of that food product. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [barcode scanner](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/BarcodeScanner) plugin then query [labelcalc](http://www.labelcalc.com/home.aspx) to get the info you need.

Comment: But that costs a small fortune, and you still need to enter in the foods information yourself, so what is the point in even scanning the barcode?

Comment: Damned if I know but I guess what you are asking for is a open source database of nutritional information. Something like: http://www.nal.usda.gov/fnic/foodcomp/search/

Comment: Yes that is it, an open source db of nutritional information. One that can be queried using a barcode number.. were on the right track.. Thank you very much.

Comment: @JoeyTawadrous Hmm, unless I'm missing something or the site has changed since 2012, I don't see barcode numbers on the usda website.

Comment: Hey @George, at the time there was plenty of barcodes! But they have since been removed. Have you had any luck elsewhere or have a specific question? I may be able to help.

Comment: Thanks for the response @JoeyTawadrous. I'm basically looking for the same thing: an UPC to nutritional info (just calories/service would suffice) API. So far I found three sources that have it: Factual, Nutritionix, and SimpleUPC. All have very limited free tiers, and a steep price jump for even the very first paid tier. None seem as comprehensive as the USDA database. Have you found any alternatives?

Comment: Your welcome @George, I found Nutritionix to be quite verbose and is what I ended up using. Some other API's seem to lack quite a lot of food products, which is what drove me to Nutritionix.

Comment: Hi @JoeyTawadrous, yup I found Nutritionix so far to be the most accurate one. However I also played with FatSecret and so far they have been able to satisfy pretty much every lookup. The data is a bit messier than Nutritionix, but they're free for startups with unlimited lookups. http://platform.fatsecret.com/api/Default.aspx?screen=prem. Worth checking out.